# Python Updating RRDTool with Serial Port Data

Tags: python, rrdtool

I am trying to update a RRDTool DB with serial information. Is it possible to declare the serial data as a variable in the update line? Using the code below, rrdtool doesn't see the N: timestamp. However if I manually enter the data following the "N:" it will update.

```
import serial
import time
import numpy
import sys
import rrdtool


ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
time.sleep(1)
ser.flush()


for i in range(2):
    ser.readline()


while 1:    
    # Read data
    temp = ser.readline()
    ret = rrdtool.update('temperature.rrd', 'N:', temp)
    if ret:
     print rrdtool.error()
     time.sleep(5)
    quit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "manually enter the data"?  Do you mean using the `rrdtool update` command on the command line, outside of Python?

Comment: If I put a number behind the N: in the python script it updates the DB. Ie 'N:65.5'

Comment: Thanks andr0x, that seems to be working, however rrdtool seems to have a problem converting the input to a float number. **Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "temperature.py", line 21, in <module>
    ret = rrdtool.update('temperature.rrd', 'N:%s' % temp)
rrdtool.error: temperature.rrd: conversion of '61.50
' to float not complete: tail '** Any ideas? It may be the decimal. I'll keep plugging away and let you know what happens

Comment: The error message says there's a space after the 0 in your `temp` variable.  That probably needs to be removed.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. Trying to remove the space now. Thanks to you both very much.

Comment: I think its the Arduino sketch adding a carriage return that is causing a whitespace.

Comment: Just wanted to post a follow up. I decided to go about this a different way and it's working well. I'm using python to read the serial port, write the serial data to a file, then use head/awk to populate the RRD. Head -c helped me to get rid of that line return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to do something like this:

```
ret = rrdtool.update('temperature.rrd', 'N:%s' % temp)
```

Each argument in an rrdtool wrapper function should correspond to an argument in the rrdtool cli command. So in your previous example when you were running rrdtool.update with 3 arguments you were actually running something like:

```
rrdtool update temperature.rrd N: 65.6
```

the update should be a single argument, so this is really what you wanted:

```
rrdtool update temperature.rrd N:65.6
```

Comment: just to be clear, I used the string format operator in my example:
http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/python25/web/str-format.html