# RRDTool and inporting serial port data

Tags: rrdtool

To start things off, I'm not a programmer so this is a 100% learning curve for me.

Project:  To capture O2 readings from an analyzer that can export this information via a serial port. Then display the latest reading and create a graph to show trending over lets say 5 hours.

I see tons of projects were people are getting temperature readings and imputing this data into a RRDTool database and graphing the data.  I'm sure I can modify the code to do what I'm looking to accomplish.

My issue is, I don't see any examples of how to capture the data that would be coming off a serial port.  Could anybody out there help a non programmer guy out?

Thank you
Mark

In the discovery mode right now.
Surfed / googled RRDTool and serial ports unable to find the information I'm looking for.

Comment: RRDTool could be used for storing, consolidating and graphing the data, if it is numerical and you're polling at regular time intervals.  However you'll need to find a way to programmatically extract the data from the serial port.  I don't know if your serial device is constantly sending, or sending on response to a query, or something else; nor what the data is and if you'd need to graph it as-is or rate of change, and so on.

Comment: Hi Steve, Thank you for the response.  The analyzer sends data out the port continuously and is adjustable from 1 sec to 59 seconds.  below is a copy of what one output string looks like:  

23/12/23 ; 16:10:10 ; O2 ; 21.50 ; % ; CO2 ; 0.13 ; %.

I would like to capture the 4th from the left item, in this case "21.50"

Comment: RRDTool needs a set of raw numbers to put into the database.  You will need to code a script or similar to read the serial port and parse the string to get the number, then call the rrdtool program to store it.  This should then be run on a regular basis (e.g. every minute or 5 minutes, depending on your requirements).  How to read the serial port will depend on the language you're coding in, and the hardware and OS you are using.  You might like to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20791340/python-updating-rrdtool-with-serial-port-data which is doing something similar in Python

Comment: Thank you Steve for the direction to look !  Have a great day.  Mark